# Цикл for с несколькими аргументами в python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Можно ли в python 3 запустить программу такого вида:

```
a = ['a','b','c','d']
for k,j in a: print(k,j)
```

Если да, то как исправить так, чтобы работала?

Comment: Что за k и j? Значение и индекс?

Comment: нет, они оба должны одинаково массив вывести. На выходе и k все что в массиве a выводит и j все что в массиве выводит

Comment: `for k in a: print(k,k)`???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Если просто нужно за одну итерацию вывести одно и то же, то можно просто выводить одно и то же по два раза (искренне ваш, Капитан Очевидность):

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for k in a:
    print(k, k)
```

Если же делать буквально то что вы хотите сделать, то можно воспользоваться функцией `zip`, передав в нее исходный список два раза:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
for k, j in zip(a, a):
    print(k, j)
```

Но особого практического смысла в этом нет, это по сути оверинжиниринг.

Смысл в такой конструкции появляется, если нужно параллельно проитерироваться по двум разным спискам, например так:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
b = ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

for k, j in zip(a, b):
    print(k, j)
```

Этот цикл выведет соответствующие элементы обоих списков попарно (т.е. `a` и `w`, `b` и `x`, и т.д.)

Comment: `zip(a, a)` напоминает `zip(it, it)` где `it=iter(a)`, но результат конечно отличается. Не нужно `zip(a,a)` использовать, чтобы путаницу не вносить. Лучше просто `print(k,k)` ограничится (первый пример).

Comment: @jfs, да, с итераторами/генераторами несколько раз так накалывался, особенно когда делаешь "отладку `print`-ами" после вывода, допустим, `list(it)` потом внезапно (на самом деле вполне ожидаемо) оказывается, что `it` уже пустой.

Comment: `zip(it, it)` это идиома, позволяющая попарно обойти итератор: `('a', 'b')`, `('c', 'd')`.  В данном случае, то что `it` расходуется при прохождении, намеренно используется. Например, если во вводе 6 элементов, то чтобы получить по 3 элемента за раз: `zip(*[iter(iterable)]*3)`. Если некратное число, то можно `zip_longest()` использовать, см. [`grouper()` рецепт в документации.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Comment: @jfs, да, видел подобный пример, но только сегодня понял, как он работает.